# How add identity and user management into aspnetcore web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity, user-management

I'm building asp.net core web api with 3 types of users: Admin, Clients and Programmers. Each of those roles have their own list of tickets. These are entity classes I've already added:

```
 public class User

    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]       
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Role Role { get; set; }

        public virtual Programmer Programmer { get; set; }

        public virtual Admin Admin { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }


public class Client
    {

        public Guid clientId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new List<Ticket>();     
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

 public class Admin
    {

        public Guid adminId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new List<Ticket>();
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

 public class Programmer
    {

        public Guid programmerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguage { get; set; }
        public Experience Experience { get; set; }
        public DetailOriented DetailOriented { get; set; }
        public FieldOfInterest FieldOfInterest { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new List<Ticket>();

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
```

I've already created regular DbContext and implemented functionality of my api using that DbContext. Now I want to change users to be IdentityUsers. I'm not sure should I make a new project where UserIdentity will be handled and then pass those users to my api(if so, how can I pass them to api and connect them with their tickets, i.e.do I leave only tickets table in api?) or make users as part of an api as I already did(if so, what would be the best way to change them into identity users so that I can query their tickets later?). Does anyone have any tips/links/similar code samples or something? I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Identity supports a single set of user profile properties. The easiest solution would be to create an `AppUser` class that inherits from IdentityUser with ALL of the properties across your user types. Also introduce an interface for each of your user types with the properties they support.

```
class AppUser: IdentityUser, IAdmin, IProgrammmer, IClient {...}
```

Based on the IdentityRole associated with the user, you can cast the AppUser instance to the appropriate interface to access the user-specific properties.